# Using BaseX 10.3 the parameter 'indent' of serializer option don't work fine

Tags: basex

I'm using BaseX 10.3.

I have assigned the following value in my .basex configuration file

```
# Local Options
SERIALIZER = indent=yes
```

But the result of my query are not indented.

If I run this query:

```
for $template in fn:collection('db/templates') 
return <template> <type>{fn:name($template/*)}</type></template>
```

This is de output:

```
<template><type>argument</type></template> 
<template><type>comment</type></template> 
<template><type>entry</type></template>
```

However, when I use serialize function with a map as the second argument works fine.

```
serialize(
for $template in fn:collection('db/templates') 
return <template> <type>{fn:name($template/*)}</type></template>,
map {'indent':'yes'})
```

the output is indented:

```
<template>
  <type>argument</type>
</template>
<template>
  <type>comment</type>
</template>
<template>
  <type>entry</type>
</template>
```

How can I get this result without using the serialize function?

Comment: Maybe there are multiple `.basex` configuration files, and the one that has been edited is not parsed when launching BaseX. What is returned by the command `SHOW OPTIONS`? For further questions, we invite you to write to the `basex-talk` mailing list.

Comment: This is de result:  `SERIALIZER: indent=yes`

Comment: This seems to be difficult to reproduce. How do you run the query / which APIs do you use?

Comment: I run query by DBA's queries panel, by GUI's queries panel and by REST requests. Alwais I get from same not indented result.